# what to do if I accidently changed .bin file?

Tags: files

I changed .bin opening file to other and I dont know how to make it back (to the normal image) I tried to use "open with" and this why it dont work

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file. Choose properties and the "open with" tab and pick a program that you can use to open "bin" files. There are several programs for this: Furius ISO Mount, Acetone Iso. But you might have some other software installed.

A reminder: ISO is a CD Rom format... in general you do not need a program for it and just burn it to a CD Rom.